# Characteristic of a tree

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

**Characteristic of a tree.**
Let $G(n,m)$ be a graph,$n$ is vertices,$m$ is degree. The following are equivalent:

1. G is a tree
2. Every two distinct vertices of $G$ are joined by a unique path
3. $G$ is connected and $m=n-1$
4. $G$ is acyclic and $m=n-1$.
   We are ask to prove  $4\implies 1$ and $3\implies 4$. Here is my proof.
   $4\implies 1$. Let $G$ be an acyclic graph and $m=n-1$. Then $G$ does not contain a cycle. Therefore, $G$ is a tree.
   $3\implies 4$. Let $G$ be an connected graph and $m=n-1$. By the assumption that the edges is $n-1$ it follows that $G$ does not contain a cycle. Therefore, $G$ is acyclic.
   Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Your proofs are incomplete.  For $4\implies1$ you need to show that $G$ is connected.  For $3\implies 4$ you've only restated the conclusion.

Comment: @User12345. For $4\implies 1$ , Since the edges of $G$ is $n-1$ it implies that it contains an $n-1$ path. Hence it is connected. For $3\implies 4$, what statement do I have to change? I am only using the definition of an acyclic to come up that $G$ is an acyclic...Please check my proof or give me a detailed proof.I am very not good in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **User**$\mathbf{12345}$ said, your original argument for $(4)\implies(1)$ is incomplete. In order show that $G$ is a tree, you must show not only that it does not contain a cycle, but also that it is connected. Since one of your hypotheses is that $G$ is acyclic, you’re already given the fact that it does not contain a cycle; your real task is to show that it must be connected.

In your response to **User**$\mathbf{12345}$ you attempted to repair the hole by arguing that since $G$ has $n-1$ edges, it must contain a path of length $n-1$ and for that reason must be connected. Here you’re making two separate claims:

- $G$ contains a path of length $n-1$; and
- if $G$ contains a path of length $n-1$, then $G$ is connected.

Both assertions require proof. Unfortunately, the first is simply false: the tree shown in the following diagram has $n$ vertices but no path of length $3$.

```
            *  
           /|\  
          * * *
```

Thus, you cannot hope to prove it, and the suggested argument therefore can’t work.

(The second assertion is true, though that hardly matters: an acyclic graph with $n$ vertices, $n-1$ edges, and a path of length $n-1$ is a [path graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph) and hence a tree.)

To prove that $G$ is connected, I suggest assuming that it is not connected and trying to get a contradiction. HINT: Show that each component of $G$ must be a tree. Then use the fact that the number of edges in any tree is $1$ less than the number of vertices to show that $G$ can have only one component.

Your attempt to prove $(3)\implies(4)$ makes no sense. Apparently you’re saying that because $G$ is connected and has $n-1$ edges, it therefore has no cycle, but you’ve given no reasoning to support that *therefore*. As **User**$\mathbf{12345}$ said, you’ve simply asserted that the result is true without offering any proof at all.

HINT: Suppose that $G$ does contain a cycle. Show that you can remove at least one edge of $G$ and still have a connected graph $H$. If $H$ contains a cycle, repeat the process. Explain why this procedure must eventually yield a tree with $n$ vertices and fewer than $n-1$ edges, which is impossible.

Comment: I have incorporated it by reading your comments which is similar to this problem.. Thank you..

Comment: @Bayoy: You’re welcome.